# How to access to side menu in all pages in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-drawer

I want to implement an application with react drawer navigation for side menu. For a simple example with three screens it work that in each screen a hamburger icon exist and with clicking on it , navigate to proper screen. My problem is that I want to add the side menu in all my pages but I don't to include all pages in side menu. I have no idea how to do it.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are NavigationActions and DrawerActions.

[Snack example](https://snack.expo.io/@kenodek/bd8657)

[And link to docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html)